# My padding doesn't work

Tags: php, while-loop, padding

I cannot understand why my padding is not working. In my div tag here:

```
<div id="show" >
            <div class="numberheader">
                <p>Tal</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="latestnumbers" style="list-style:none;padding-top: 60px;">
                <?php include('response.php');?>
            </ul>           
        </div>
```

I am calling a number from my php script response.php:

```
<?php 
//echo "kuagdjagd";
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//include('session.php');

// Selecting Database
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';
$pad_left_values = array(0 => 20, 1 => 20, 2 => 20, 3 => 20, 4 => 40, 5 => 20, 6 => 40, 7 => 20, 8 => 20, 9 => 40, 10 => 20, 11 => 20, 12 => 20);

    // '?' er placeholders for variabler
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM numbertable ORDER BY num_id DESC LIMIT 9;");

    // execute prepared statement 
    $stmt->execute();

    // gør variabler klar:    
    $number = null;    
    $n_id = null;

    /* bind result variabler */
    $stmt->bind_result($n_id, $number);

    /* fetch values for hver row, her kun 1 row dog: */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $pad = ($number >= 1 && $number <= 12? $pad_left_values[$number]: $pad_left_values[0]);

        echo "<li><div style='padding-left: ".$pad."px;'".$number."</div></li>";
    }    

    // luk statement                        
    $stmt->close();

    // luk connection
    $mysqli->close();                   

?>
```

If I fx put the number 1 in my form field, it should have a padding on 20px;

Can anybody see why it is not working?

After I have made this code I am not getting any output anymore. That means that no numbers are shown in my div tag:

Comment: How does the output of your php script look like? Is the style attribute correct?

Comment: @M375: Have you checked in browser's inspect element?

Comment: provide your view source code... ctr+u in mozila.. and provide html source code.  of <div id='show'> block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have missed close div '>'tag.

I think $number should be at outside div.

Write this line as:-

```
 echo "<li><div style='padding-left: ".$pad."px;'>$number</div></li>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It still dosent help :-/

Comment: @some-non-descript-user: We are on same track bro ;)

Comment: Are you guys still active on the threat here? It was just because I had a second question. What if I wanted to give some of the numbers the color blue, could I style that in my echo tag?

Comment: Yes.  you need to write color : blue in style tag.

Answer (score 2):

**try this one..**

If you writing code in " " doublequotes.. you can access varibale value directly.

```
echo "<li><div style='padding-left:$padpx;'>$number</div></li>";
```